# Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать в картинке

Tags: css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать в картинке

```css
.zvonok {
  height: 148px;
  background-color: rgba(#fd5f00, .1);
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.zvonok__div {
  margin-bottom: -100px;
}

.zvonok__img {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section class="zvonok">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class='zvonok__div'>
          <img src="img/Layer_1.png" alt="#" class='zvonok__img'>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: На будущее, нельзя писать hex в rgb\\rgba (`background-color: rgba(#fd5f00, .1);`).

Comment: [Полезны ли вопросы-картинки и как можно улучшить ситуацию?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5298/183314)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не шарю в бутстрапе, вот такой вариант сделал.

```css
.block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff7f2;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 20px 0 40px;
}

.wrap {
  display: block;
  max-width: 470px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrap::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.image, .info {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
}

.image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.image .name {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: .8rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.info {
  width: calc(100% - 120px);
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.title {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.description {
  font-size: .8rem;
}

.number {
  font-size: .9rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fd5f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkSSq.png">
      <div class="name">Менеджер Катя</div>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <div class="title">Есть вопросы? Звоните!</div>
      <div class="description">Менеджер с удовольствием на них ответит!</div>
      <div class="number">+7 (123) 456-78-90</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: подскажите как адаптировать таблицу ?

Comment: вы быть хоть расписали для других людей, чем ваш ответ ценен

Comment: @mymedia простите дядя не хотел вас обидеть